# How to send commands in another shell via ssh using python or perl

Tags: python, bash, shell, perl, ssh

I need to establish an ssh connection and execute commands remotely, and the flow is: connect by ssh, open a new shell by command line and finally execute the commands.

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new('test.com');
$ssh->login('user', 'pass');
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd('shell');
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd('ls -l');
print($stdout);
```

but when you run $ssh->cmd('shell'); it waits, I assume that this opens the shell and since it is a "command" that does not end, it does not pass to the next command which would be to make an ls.

I need to execute commands in the new shell opened by ssh. It is not possible to modify absolutely anything on the remote machine.

Any solution in perl or python will help :)

Comment: `ssh` already runs the given command in a new shell. There's no need to start a shell yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to start a new shell explicitly. That's how `ssh` runs a given command, by passing it as a command line to a new shell.

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new('test.com');
$ssh->login('user', 'pass');
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd('ls -l');
print($stdout);
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl CPAN recommends to use `Net::OpenSSH` [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#Net::OpenSSH-Vs.-Net::SSH::.*-modules) instead of `Net::SSH::Perl`.

Here is the snippet how it should look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::OpenSSH;

#Function declaration by passing host, user and password as an arguments
my $ssh = ConnectToRemoteMachine ("host_ip_address", "user", "password");

my $result_ls    = $ssh->capture("ls -l");
my $result_shell = $ssh->capture("shell");

print "Result of ls:\n";
print $result_ls."\n";

print "Shell: $result_shell\n"

undef $ssh;
.
.
#Function definition 
sub ConnectToRemoteMachine {
    my ( $host, $user, $passwd ) = @_;
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host,
                                user => $user,
                                password => $passwd);
    $ssh->error and die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;

    return $ssh;
}
```